# What BMX Frame Do I Have?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

Restoring a BMX i got maybe in '96-'97. I bought it off a friend and its a chromoly frame and has the serial number stamp on the front head tube on the frame (0950921035). It looks "close" to an '85 GT Performer. but has some small differences. I want to restore it. How can I find this info?? THX!

Comment: Ask the friend who sold it to you?  Sadly, a serial number is pretty useless unless you already know the brand AND that manufacturer kept records.   Its unlikely there are "brand specific parts" unless you're going for an as-original rebuild.  Good luck with your future riding!

Comment: I looked up some Power Lite's and they are similar but not it. Is there a way to upload pictures on here?

Answer (score 0):

It's a "power lite"

Look where the back wheel mounts, (rear dropouts?) and there might be a "p" marked right there but not always.

Comment: Interesting - do you have any supporting information?  The question is quite sparse on detail - how do you get to this as an answer?    I'm not doubting, just that we get a lot of ID my BMX questions and they're very hard to answer.    Welcome to the site too - do take a moment to go read the [tour] which shows some of the more unique features of Stackexchange.